# Multi-robot Navigation - Cooperative Navigation

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-kinetic, local-planner, 2dcostmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have setup navigation stack successfully . I have following configuration :

- Mutiple bots under different namespaces
- Seperate Planners for individual bots
- Static Map generated before-hand
- No laser scans, only gps and odometry

I want bots to avoid colliding into each other. I think the navigation stack doesn't have such a capability yet.
Avoidance based upon location of there neighbour bots.

Is there any way navigation package provides that utility?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296017/multi-robot-navigation---cooperative-navigation/) by [MandeepSingh](https://answers.ros.org/users/36206/mandeepsingh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2018-07-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [simbha](https://answers.ros.org/users/29493/simbha/) on 2018-07-03**:
I think you have to write your own algorithm to do same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I have figured a way out,
I am using social navigation layer in creating my CostMap.
Though it requires lidar scans to look for people, since my robots are connected over internet I am subscribing to their poses and publishing onto people topic which navigation layer uses.

So I can do co-operative navigation using GPS and network only.

---

Originally posted by [MandeepSingh](https://answers.ros.org/users/36206/mandeepsingh/) with karma: 46 on 2018-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1